# T-SQL aggregate window functions over specific time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions

Here's a SQL 2012 table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_BID]
(
    [ID] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [VALUE] [smallint] NULL,
    [DT_START] [date] NULL,
    [DT_FIN] [date] NULL
)
```

I can easily get last event's value, time since last event (or any specific lags) by LAG window function, as well as total number of events (or over specific number of past events), total average per user, etc

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    [VALUE],
    [DT_START], [DT_FIN],
    -- days since the end of last event
    DATEDIFF(d, LAG([DT_FIN], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DT_FIN]),
    [DT_START]) AS LAG1_DT,
    -- value of the last event
    LAG([VALUE], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DT_FIN]) AS LAG1_VALUE,
    -- number of events per id
    COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS N,
    -- average [value] per id
    ROUND(AVG(CAST([VALUE] as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID), 1) AS VAL_AVG
FROM 
    TBL_BID
```

I am trying to get for events happened over **specified time interval**, i.e *10 days, 30 days, 180 days, etc, before the **start date of each event***

- count of events
- average of [VALUE]
- average time in days between the end of event and start of the next one

Something along the lines of:

```
COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DT_FIN 
                RANGE BETWEEN DATEDIFF(d,-30,[DT_START]) AND [DT_START] )
```

UPDATE 4/19/2017:
Some statistics
About 20MM IDs, the time interval is 5 years, 
mean number of events per ID is 3.0. It could be 100+ events per ID, but majority has only handful of events, the distribution is very right skewed

```
Events_per_ID   Number_IDs
1   18676221
2   11254167
3   6992200
4   4487664
5   2933183
6   1957433
7   1330040
8   918873
9   644229
10  457858
........
```

Comment: You can not use datediff inside of window function over statement.

Comment: Standard also support it, but current realisation of T-SQL in SQL Server is not.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко . . . To be specific, you are referring to the windowing clause.  `DATEDIFF()` (or any other function) is find in the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко I figured it is not possible to use :) Hence is my question what are the options :)

Comment: Can 2 events with the same ID also have the same DT_START / DT_FIN?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz 
No, it can not be 
(ID, DT_START, DT_FINISH) is a unique key
it is possible that DT_START = DT_FINISH for the same ID, and LAG(DT_FINISH,1)=DT_START, i.e. finish of one event is start for another event for the same ID

Comment: Hi, can you please give some data demographics? number of IDs, average  number of events per ID, years of data (max(dt_start)-min(dt_start)?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz actually after looking at the entire data set it turned out that there are some cases when  (ID, DT_START, DT_FINISH) is repeated. Some are data entry errors (easy to clean) and some others are multiple events per day. I've added ID_ROW to the set to make (ID, ID_ROW, DT_START,DT_FINISH) unique. If having  (ID, DT_START, DT_FINISH) unique helps a lot, we can drop duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is `outer apply`:

```
select . . .,
       b.cnt_30
from TBL_BID b outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt_30
      from TBL_BID b2
      where b2.id = b.id and
            b2.dt_start >= dateadd(day, -30, b.dt_start) and
            b2.dt_start <= b.dt_start
     ) b;
```

This is not necessarily really efficient.  You can readily extend it by adding more `outer apply` subqueries.

Comment: How "expensive" it is? The table has [hundreds] of millions of rows. Will it still work?

Comment: @AlexLizz . . . You need to try to see if it works on your data.  You'll want to be sure there is an index on `tbl_bid(id, dt_start)` before trying.

Comment: Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.
Msg 1011, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The correlation name 'b' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

Comment: When I tried the second snippet I get 

   >>Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression    containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.<<

Answer (score 0):

Need some more information, but the basic idea is to transform the windows functions type from `range` to `rows` by generating the full range of dates for each ID.

- For each ID generate the relevant range of days (`min(dt_start)-180` to `max(dt_start)`)
- Use the above row set as a base and LEFT JOIN `TBL_BID` on `id` and `dt_fin` (if `(id,dt_fin)` is not unique, aggregate first)
- Use windows functions partition by id order by date rows between 180/30/10 preceding and current row